# How do I set the build path in cmake?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

I am a total newb to cmake, I am kind of overwhelmed at the moment.

The library I am using creates a visual studio project file using cmake. I would like to edit the cmake file so that it changes the "Output Directory" of the visual studio project to "../../../build/$(Configuration)/". I have no idea how to do this though.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these lines to your `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
set(dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../build)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${dir} CACHE PATH "Build directory" FORCE)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${dir} CACHE PATH "Build directory" FORCE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and ended up using CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY to set it. For your case it would be:
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../build)